# Moodle: Login automatically in moodle website using external website's google sso id_token

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, moodle, google-sso

I have a wordpress website in which i have logged in using google sso and i have a id_token of google sso for that login. Now i want to login directly(without showing login page) to another website which is built in moodle from that logged in wordpress website's dashboard page using that id_token. I have changes ready in wordpress website. How can i achieve that from moodle side. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use oauth2 authentication with Google in Moodle - see https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/OAuth_2_authentication

Comment: Hi @RussellEngland , I have created google service using ouath2 client-id and secret parameters which works well with moodle default login page. Now i want to user to redirect into moodle dashboard without using login page using id_token param of google(which i got from credential parameter after authentication). What changes i have to make in the current implementation?